# Can I open a file as a different type than specified by its extension?

Tags: vim

We have a bunch of sql files with no extension on the file name. I'd like to open them as sql files for syntax highlighting, custom indentation depth, etc., but I don't want to have to rename the files to add the extension every time I want to edit them (and let's just say that they have to stay extensionless).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is described in `:help` section `usr_06.txt` on syntax highlighting.

You can turn syntax highlighting on and set the filetype this way:

```
:syntax enable
:set filetype=sql
```

Comment: Is there a way to put this in an rc file and load using `-u` at vim launch? In my tests it gets overridden by the file type extension's syntax highlighting and only works for files without associated syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Are they in an identified location? All in one directory? If so, you can do:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufEnter /path/to/directory/* set ft=sql
```

Otherwise you'll have to write your own file detection routine.

Comment: In this case they are, and this works very nicely, thanks!